# MacOS Mojave and pg_connect with SSL

Tags: php, postgresql, macos-mojave

I'm running `Mac OS X` with `Mojave` and default `Apache` and `PHP`.

I'm trying to connect to a `PostgreSQL` with `SSL`/`TLS`, but are getting the error:

```
Warning: pg_pconnect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: sslmode value "require" invalid when SSL support is not compiled in in ..
```

However, running `pg_config --configure` does show the `'--with-openssl'` flag.

Running `phpinfo` however shows under `pgsql` that `SSL` is disabled.

But directly from the terminal I am able to use command line `psql` with `SSL`.

Answer (score 1):

I was also stuck on the same issue, here's how I solved it

The default PHP of MacOS 10.14 (Mojave) doesn't have SSL enabled in its php pgsql extension

To manually install SSL certificate into the php pgsql extension would be possible but
troublesome

Instead, you can install a new version of php, which would indeed install all it's extensions again also with a php postgres extension with ssl enabled

First install homebrew if you don't have it, then install php as shown below
I installed php 7.3, as I had Catalina it came with 7.3.11 (it got upgraded to 7.3.21)

```
brew update
brew install php@7.3
brew link php@7.3
```

If you updated Mojave to Catalina, you may want to also add this after the above is done

```
brew link php@7.3 --force
```

After the above is done you just need to link it to your $PATH which can be done as:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/sbinbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

If you updated Mojave to Catalina, instead of the above do this
(since Catalina changed default shell to Zsh)

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.3/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Reload the terminal or open a new one, type in

```
php -v (the version should be changed)
```

And then type php -i, goto pgsql section

```
pgsql

PostgreSQL Support => enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version => 12.3
PostgreSQL(libpq)  => PostgreSQL 12.3 on x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0, compiled by Apple 
clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59), 64-bit
Multibyte character support => enabled
SSL support => enabled
Active Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pgsql.allow_persistent => On => On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent => Off => Off
pgsql.ignore_notice => Off => Off
pgsql.log_notice => Off => Off
pgsql.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
pgsql.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
```

You should see SSL support enabled.

Comment: switched php versions and worked for me as well, thanks!